# Removing duplicates in Elasticsearch cross cluster search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using cross cluster search and searching for a document by _id that exists in both clusters.
ES returns with 2 hits (1 in local index, 1 in remote index). I just want the one in the local index. How can I remove the duplicate from the remote cluster ?

Query :

````
{
"query": {
"terms": {
"_id": [ "123"]
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able achieving this by using `Field Collapsing`over the `_id`-field and define a sorting condition in which documents from your local cluster rank higher (e.g a cluster id, or a timestamp etc)

(see [Elasticsearch Reference: Field Collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse))

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Unfortunately the _id field is not defined as keyword/numeric, so collapse errors out -
unknown type for collapse field `_id`, only keywords and numbers are accepted
Any workaround ?
Query -

```{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ "123"]
    }
  },
    "collapse" : {
        "field" : "_id" 
    },
    "sort": ["date"], 
    "from": 10 
}```

Comment: Simply change your mapping to copy the id into a field of type keyword with `copy_to` mapping parameter.
After changing your mapping perform an `update_by_query` on your index to make sure the new field is populated.

Comment: sorry for the delay, was able to verify this today. Works just as expected after making it a keyword. Thank you very much !